# Error in MySQL syntax when trying to pass use the ' symbol when contained within data

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   [Unable post text to MySQL using "Insert Into"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315711/unable-post-text-to-mysql-using-insert-into)

When passing Movie titles into MySQL database using PHP, I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Dreams' )' at line 10
```

Here is my code:

```
//Getting a list of all the users friends
$MyFriends=$facebook->api('/me/friends');

//Loop through friends array to identify each friend
$c=0;
while ($c<count($MyFriends['data']))
{
    $N=$MyFriends['data'][$c]['name'];
    $I=$MyFriends['data'][$c]['id'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO UserFriends
    (
        UserFBID, 
        FriendFBID,
        DisplayName
    ) VALUES
    (
        '$FBID', 
        '$I',
        '$N'
    ) ") or die(mysql_error()); 

    //Getting a list of friends each movie likes
    $friendId = "/" . $I . "/movies";
    $myFriendsMovies=$facebook->api($friendId);

    //Loop through to identify each movie
    $x=0;
    while ($x<count($myFriendsMovies['data']))
    {
        $r = $myFriendsMovies['data'][$x]['id'];
        $s = $myFriendsMovies['data'][$x]['name'];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO LinkedMovies 
        (
            UserFBID, 
            MovieFBID,
            MovieName
        ) VALUES
        (
            '$I', 
            '$r',
            '$s'
        ) ") or die(mysql_error());         
        $x=$x+1;
    }
    $c=$c+1;
}
```

It seems the variable $s has picked up the movie 'Akira Kurosawa's Dreams' and keeps bombing out of the loop, with the above error.

Comment: Have you ever considered using the proper database escaping function? Accepting random user input and putting it into queries [isn't very advisable](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: [Preferrably don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They aren't actively maintained [and are officially discouraged](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

```
$N=$MyFriends['data'][$c]['name'];
```

Should be:

```
$N = mysql_real_escape_string($MyFriends['data'][$c]['name']); // sanitize the data, do this for all external data input
```

Also:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

You should use code like following `mysql_real_escape_string` function for safe sql queries and escape string before execute sql queries

```
//Getting a list of all the users friends
$MyFriends=$facebook->api('/me/friends');

//Loop through friends array to identify each friend
$c=0;
while ($c<count($MyFriends['data']))
{
    $N=mysql_real_escape_string( $MyFriends['data'][$c]['name'] );
    $I=mysql_real_escape_string( $MyFriends['data'][$c]['id'] );
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO UserFriends
    (
        UserFBID, 
        FriendFBID,
        DisplayName
    ) VALUES
    (
        '$FBID', 
        '$I',
        '$N'
    ) ") or die(mysql_error()); 

    //Getting a list of friends each movie likes
    $friendId = "/" . $I . "/movies";
    $myFriendsMovies=$facebook->api($friendId);

    //Loop through to identify each movie
    $x=0;
    while ($x<count($myFriendsMovies['data']))
    {
        $r = mysql_real_escape_string( $myFriendsMovies['data'][$x]['id'] );
        $s = mysql_real_escape_string( $myFriendsMovies['data'][$x]['name']);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO LinkedMovies 
        (
            UserFBID, 
            MovieFBID,
            MovieName
        ) VALUES
        (
            '$I', 
            '$r',
            '$s'
        ) ") or die(mysql_error());         
        $x=$x+1;
    }
    $c=$c+1;
}
```